# Using the Panorama for only part of the App

Tags: windows-phone-7, panorama-control

I'm new to WP7, coming from .Net/Silverlight.
I like the Panorama idea, which would work well with the application I have in mind. However, on the side of the panorama, I need to have a few other screens which do not interact with the main Panorama, so I was thinking of creating a menu at the beginning to select in which branch the user wants to go. 
Can I use the Panorama app to meet this need, or do I need to do a classic app and handle myself the screen transitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the panorama.

It's quite common for a panorama to have an item which is a menu containing links to other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you have a better picture of how you can embed menu in your panorama control:

http://mobilewares.net/images/WP7/BSRV1/sm/panorama.png